# how to look up a columns and choose a value when there are replications in column headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that looks like this:

```
|      | headerA   | headerB    | headerC    | headerD    | headerA    | headerA    |
| VAL  | 1         |2           |3           |4           |6           |9           |  
| DATE | 2020      | 2021       |2022        | 2020       | 2024       |2023        |
```

There are more rows but I only need val and date. There are also a lot of columns. I don't know the row number for data and value.
In another sheet I want to gather VAL for headerA, headerB and headerC. When there are multiple columns with same key(headerA), I want to choose the one that has the latest date. In the example above, headerA-> 6, headerB->2 and headerC->3. I know how to write this with "vlookup" and "match" when there is no replication of headers
vlookup("VAL",sheet1!$A$1:$zz$1000, match("headerA", sheet1!$A$1:$zz$1,0),false)

but I don't know how to do it now that I need to choose the one with the latest date. Is it possible?

*I realized I tagged this post incorrectly with Excel but I am using google sheets. Also I am not sure if it matters but my data is actually in another document so I am using IMPORTRANGE.

Comment: What is your excel version? Do you have `Excel365`?

Answer (score 1):

With `Excel365` Try below formula.

```
=XLOOKUP(1,($B$1:$G$1=B6)*($B$3:$G$3=MAXIFS($B$3:$G$3,$B$1:$G$1,B6)),$B$2:$G$2,"")
```

For other version of excel try-

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$2:$G$2,($B$1:$G$1=B6)*($B$3:$G$3=MAX(IF($B$1:$G$1=B6,$B$3:$G$3,0))))
```

You may need to array entry for excel `Non365` versions. Array entry means enter formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I just realized I tagged this incorrectly, I am using Google Sheets. Do you know what would be the formula there with vlookup?

Comment: Sumproduct formula will also work in google-sheet. Give a try please.

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365, try:

[image]

Formula in `J1`:

```
=@SORT(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B2:G3,B1:G1=I1)),2,-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In google sheets, you can use this:

#### Formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("<url of sheets>","<sheet name>!<header range>"))), 
SORT(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTRANGE("<url of sheets>","<sheet name>!<data range>")), 3, 0),
{1, 2, 3}, 0)))
```

#### Sample data:

[image: sample data]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- If you only want to show the first 2 columns, then modify `{1, 2, 3}` into `{1, 2}`
- This will take any number of columns for your data.